# Primefaces 6: disable button Upload with fileUpload component with mode simple

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using Primefaces 6 and I create a fileUpload component as below:

```
                <p:fileUpload id="myId" 
                          styleClass="MY-STYLE" 
                          value="#{bean.objUploadedFile}" 
                          mode="simple" 
                          skinSimple="true" 
                          multiple="false"
                          update="@form"
                          label="Choose"
            >
            </p:fileUpload>
```

I must use `mode=simple` so ajax is false. I add then a button to manage the upload:

```
                <p:commandButton id="btnId" 
                             value="Upload" 
                             disabled="#{myBean.btnDisabled}"
                             process="@form"
                             update="@form"
                             ajax="false"
                             actionListener="#{myBean.manageUpload}" 
            />
```

This button is loaded with `disable=true` to startup.
Can I set `disable=false` for this button when user click on Choose button in the fileUpload component? I tried with javascript but it does not work. 
Is it possible?

Comment: U need to use ajax I guess to update the button while file is uploading.

Comment: And how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible, I tried and discovered that fileUpload  is a "non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent" (aka. no p:ajax ).

The second option would be use one of the java script events of the generated input type="file" ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file ), but prime faces do not expose then...

Wich means  the jsf - prime faces way, at least in simple mode, is to let the button always enable and validate file selection on form submit.

Although if you really want/need enable the button on file selection, you can use jquery to attach a event listener to the input type="file" that will enable the button, but this option is kinda of hack, so I don't recomend it because prime-faces and jsf tend to be unforgiving when you mess around with their expected component behaviors.